# command substitution within c style for loop in Zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, command-substitution

I have a function printing a number

```
myFunc() {
    echo 11
}
```

Now I want to use the number in expression in c style for-loop:

```
for (( i=1; i<=$(myFunc); i++ )); do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Zsh gave me

```
test.sh:5: parse error near `i++ '
test.sh:6: parse error near `i<=$(myFunc); i++ ))...'
```

while Bash prints 1 through 11 as expected. What happened to Zsh? I expect it to be compatible with Bash on this feature.

In case it matters, my environment:

- OS X 10.11.5
- zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0)
- GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)

## update

This may be a bug, and may have been fixed in latest version. I will delete this question as soon as I verify this.

Comment: A general pondering: Why would you write code for one language and expect it to be understood by the interpreter of another? Just make the script run in `bash`.

Comment: @Kusalananda How about completion? I run those script with `source filename`. It would take a lot of time to translate it to Zsh.

Comment: @jimmij So it seems that I need to update my Zsh? I will try the latest version.

Comment: What about completion? Bash and Zsh has different programmable completion systems. In any case, this looks like a bug in the OS X `zsh` that was fixed somewhere between versions. I have looked at the full commit history for `zsh`, but I have found no mentioning of fixing it (though I might not have searched for the right strings).

Comment: @Kusalananda Currently there is [a comprehensive completion repository for Bash in OS X](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-completions), but nothing equivalent for Zsh in OS X. It's a pity if that repository is not useful to Zsh users.

Comment: This is getting off-topic real quick now. I'm no Zsh user, but the people using it seems to like the oh-my-zsh extensions, which seems to be possibly similar. http://ohmyz.sh/

Comment: @Kusalananda I am already using Oh-My-Zsh, but I forgot that it involves completion. I found the plugin I need. Thank you very much! I will delete this question as soon as I verify that it is a bug already fixed in latest version.

Comment: Don't delete it! That would prevent others to find the issue. Instead, answer it yourself and in two days time (required waiting period), accept your own answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda All right. I will provide more information after that.

Answer (score 0):

It works in my zsh:

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ myFunc() {
    echo 11
}
$ for (( i=1; i<=$(myFunc); i++ )); do
    echo "$i"
done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
$
```

It might just have been a bug.